# Is there any benefit to an index when the column is only used for (hash) joining?

Tags: sql-server, oracle, join, indexing

Lets say that a column will only be used for joining. (i.e. I won't be ordering on the column, nor will a search for specific values in the column individually) ... the only thing that I will use the column for is joining to another table.

If the database supports Hash Joins (which from my understanding don't benefit from indexes) .. then wouldn't the addition of an index be completely redundant? (and wasteful) ?

Comment: how do you know the database will (always) use hash joins for joins to this table???

Comment: Given proper statistics ... I would assume that the cost based optimizer would be smart enough to pick hash join over a much more costly nested loop (without indexes).

Comment: there's no way to guarantee how Oracle will execute your SQL, explain plan can change, data can change, stats can change, ...

Comment: By not adding an index you also make it much less likely that a merge join will be used as that would require a sort step to be added first. Also is this joining column in an FK relationship as validating the FK could make use of the indexes.

Comment: there's no way to guarantee how Oracle will execute your SQL --- of-course ..  I would assume for small tables Oracle wouldn't even bother hashing join, and would just use a nested loop ... but given proper stats I think its reasonable to assume that Oracle would use a cheaper Hash Join over a Nested loop when dealing with a lot of data, with no indexes.

Comment: Good point about the FK contraints ... I didn't even think of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL Server it will still prevent a `Key Lookup`.

If you `JOIN` on an unindexed field, the server needs to get the values for that field from the clustered index.

If you `JOIN` on a NC index, the values can be obtained directly without loading all the data pages from the cluster (which really is the whole table).

So essentially you save yourself a lot of IO as the first step filters down based on a very narrow index instead of on the entire table loaded from disk.

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean ... Either way the Hash Join will have to iterate once through each table ... i.e. once through once table to generate hash values for each join clause .. and then once through the other table to match rows up to the generated hash table.  I would almost think that having a non-clustered index (i.e. plain old heap table) .. would even be a bit faster ( data takes up less space in a heap table then clustered index).

Comment: No, it'll iterate through the **index** not through the table.  That's less data = less pages = less IO = faster.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something .. but if I'm iterating through everything (100% of rows) .. where's the speed gain from having an index?

Comment: @vicjugador You are missing something. All indexes are not equal.  Think of it like a book.  If you have a book that has a list of items and all their values (the clustered index), and another book that just has a list of all the different values for one aspect (the NC index), you can fit a lot more entries in the second book per page, and read a lot fewer pages to get the same information.  SQL pulls a lot less data from a narrow NC index and can process it faster.